# Windows 10 laptop won't join domain but can ping the domain controller

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I have a Windows 10 laptop but it is refusing to join the domain controller. This is the result of my `ip config / all` (I obviously hid the domain to protect security).

As you see there is no primary DNS Suffix so I am presuming that is the issue. Here is the Windows IP Configuration:

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DavidLaptop  
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :   
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . :  
Hybrid  IP Routing Enabled. . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No     
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : MYGROUP

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : MYGROUP    
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM    
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B4-B6-86-37-C3-A3    
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes    
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.102(Preferred)    
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0    
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 03 May 2018 09:49:16    
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 05 May 2018 09:49:15    
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.252    
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.201    
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.201
                                    192.168.10.252    
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected    
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)    
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 90-61-AE-B2-F5-BA    
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes    
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

The laptop is a HP Zen Book 17" with factory install of Windows 10 Pro

Comment: hi nbite may I ask how you formated that correct i tried quote but it messed it up